# Thread local storage

Tags: c#, .net

what is the best way to store some variable local to each thread?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can indicate that static variables should be stored per-thread using the [`[ThreadStatic]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static int foo;
```

Comment: Can I store static List of objects per-thread with this attribute?

Comment: @DainiusKreivys Yes! No matter what the type of variable is, its unique instance will be maintained per thread as long as you are using `[ThreadStatic]` attribute. I did a quick test using `[ThreadStatic]
        private static List<int> foo = new List<int> { 20, 30 };`. Then, on another thread I initialized the same foo variable with a list containing three integers and when that thread ended my original list containing two elements referred by main thread remained intact.

Answer (score 60):

If you use .Net 4.0 or above, as far as I know, the recommended way is to use [`System.Threading.ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) which also gives lazy initialization as a bonus.

Comment: This method is also not limited to static fields.

Answer (score 19):

Another option in the case that scope is an issue you can used Named Data Slots
e.g.

```
    //setting
    LocalDataStoreSlot lds =  System.Threading.Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot("foo");
    System.Threading.Thread.SetData(lds, "SomeValue");

    //getting
    LocalDataStoreSlot lds = System.Threading.Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("foo");
    string somevalue = System.Threading.Thread.GetData(lds).ToString();
```

This is only a good idea if you can't do what James Kovacs and AdamSane described

Comment: Does named data slots work with the new `async Task` model? Is there something extra needed to make a slot available in the task?

Comment: @Jaans See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555255/how-to-maintain-thread-context-across-async-await-model-in-c

Answer (score 8):

Other option is to pass in a parameter into the thread start method. You will need to keep in in scope, but it may be easier to debug and maintain.