# Exchange arbitrary objects between assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, static, .net-4.0

In my C# application I am loading several assemblies into one Application. In order to quickly exchange objects between the assemblies, I am looking for an existing class in the commonly available .NET namespace that I could "abuse" to exchange generic objects.

I was thinkging about `System.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` but this one supports strings only. Is there one which has an `object` type?

I know this is a terrible solution to exchange data between assemblies, but I cant change the interfaces right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do this:

```
// Assembly 1
SomeSuperGlobal.Set("someKey", new Foo { Bar = "baz" });

// Assembly 2
var foo = SomeSuperGlobal.Get("someKey");
```

First off a warning, what you have is a terrible design. You [should not let your code rely on global state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil), those practices have been abolished since the sixties at least. Do not do this, and thoroughly consider redesigning the application.

That being said, you could [use named data slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190764/thread-local-storage):

```
// Assembly 1
LocalDataStoreSlot dataSlot =  System.Threading.Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot("someKey");
System.Threading.Thread.SetData(dataSlot, new Foo { Bar = "baz" });

// Assembly 2
LocalDataStoreSlot dataSlot = System.Threading.Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("someKey");
var foo = System.Threading.Thread.GetData(dataSlot);
```

Be sure to read [`Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot()`'s documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.allocatenameddataslot(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thx, thats exactly what im looking for. im gonna try it and then report back.